# Using a nullable string resource id from view model in Android data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-xml, android-databinding

I am trying to map API errors (exceptions) to String resources in my view model. My view model looks like the following.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class AccountViewModel @Inject constructor(accountRepository: AccountRepository) : ViewModel() {

  val isLoadingProfile = MutableLiveData(false)
  val profile = MutableLiveData<Profile>()
  val profileLoadError = MutableLiveData<Int>()

  fun loadProfile() {
    isLoadingProfile.postValue(true)
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      try {
        profile.postValue(accountRepository.getProfile())
      } catch (e: Throwable) {

        // assign String resource id to profileLoadError
        profileLoadError.postValue(
          when (e) {
            is NetworkError -> R.string.network_error
            else -> R.string.unknown_error
          }
        )

      } finally {
        isLoadingProfile.postValue(false)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my error text view XML looks like the following.

```xml
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@{viewModel.profileLoadError ?? ``}"
  android:visibility="@{viewModel.profileLoadError != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

But I am getting a class cast exception when I try to run it.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

If I remove the `null` coalescing operator from the data binding expression like the following, I get a resource not found exception.

```
android:text="@{viewModel.profileLoadError}"
```

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

I know that it is kind of an idiotic question, but how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestion from @androidLearner, I created a binding adapter for the `android:text` attribute.

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun TextView.setText(@StringRes resId: Int?) {
  resId ?: return
  if (resId == ResourcesCompat.ID_NULL) {
    text = ""
  } else {
    setText(resId)
  }
}
```

Now, I can pass the string id without worrying about its nullability.

```xml
android:text="@{viewModel.profileLoadError}"
```

Answer (score 0):

is NetworkError -> R.string.network_error  ->in this line you are returning String to post value for profileLoadError of type Int.That's why you got ClassCastException.

So change the type of LiveData  to String

**val profileLoadError = MutableLiveData()**

Comment: I could, but it is a known anti-pattern https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/locale-changes-and-the-androidviewmodel-antipattern-84eb677660d9

Comment: what you can do, create binding adapter function for that text view and pass that String resource Id and the view .then try to setText for text view based on id in  adapter.@as